# How to sort contributions tab on github?

Tags: github

On github there is a default tab called `Contributions`. Can I change the sorting logic to something other than the default one?

Answer (score 0):

You do have a combo list which allows you to see contributors by:

- addition
- Deletion
- commit

The other way would be to use the [GitHub statistics API](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/#contributors)  to get a list of contributors, and sort them yourself with any criteria you want:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors
```